# Zsh erroring because of call to launch tmux? -> "(eval):1: parse error near `>', ..."

Tags: zsh, tmux

I am getting the following error:

```
(eval):1: parse error near `>'
(eval):1: parse error in command substitution
```

With this added to my .zshrc:

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]
then
    tmux attach -t TMUX || tmux new -s TMUX
fi
```

I am running tmux version 3.2a installed today 2022-03-10 with brew. I have never had this problem before, and I am quite positive this worked yesterday on my computer.

Comment: As you can see from the error message, the parse error is reported by `eval`, but in the code you posted, there is no `eval` statement. Therefore the error message is not present in the code shown here. If you suspect that your `tmux` call is related to the error (you can test this by commenting out the line, respectively running the `tmux` command manually from the command line), it means that one of the startup files run by the shell, which has been started by `tmux`, is responsible for the error.

Comment: That's right, there is no eval in my .zshrc, yet it mentions it. It was the first thing I greped for as well. I am very confused by this error.

Comment: The `eval` can be in some other file. If you have admin rights, put a `set -x` into `/etc/zshenv`and repeat your experiment. This should show you at which point the `eval` occurs. Of course remove the trace statement immediately afterwards.